# Arduino NodeJs Serial Communication issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, serial-port, serial-communication

I cant send data from NodeJs to Arduino.. Serial.available() is false all time.. I dont know what is the my fail.. Can anyone help me ?

**This is my JavaScript/NodeJS code**

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;

var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", {
  baudrate: 9600,
         dataBits: 8, 
         parity: 'none', 
         stopBits: 1, 
         flowControl: false
});

serialPort.on("open", function () {
  console.log('open');
serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
data="omg";
   for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        serialPort.write(new Buffer(data[i], 'ascii'), function(err, results) {
           if(err!=null)
           {
             console.log('Error: ' + err);
           }
           else
           console.log('Results ' + results);
        });
    }
});
```

**And This is my Arduino Code**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
String inData = "";

void loop(){

    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char received = Serial.read();
        inData.concat(received);
        Serial.println(received);
        // Process message when new line character is received
        if (received == '\n') {
            // Message is ready in inDate
        }
    }
}
```

**NodeJs OutPut is**

> node server.js DEPRECATION: Please use `require('serialport')` instead
>   of `require('serialport').SerialPort`
>
> open
>
> Result : undefinded
>
> Result : undefinded
>
> Result : undefinded

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen nodeJS ^^.

Replace :

`var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;`

by

`var SerialPort = require("serialport");`

EDIT :

Your `data` isn't initialize in your scope.
try this :

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport");

var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", {
  baudrate: 9600,
     dataBits: 8, 
     parity: 'none', 
     stopBits: 1, 
     flowControl: false
});

var _data = '';

serialPort.on("open", function () {
  console.log('open');
  serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    _data += data;
  });
   for(var i=0; i<_data.length; i++){
    serialPort.write(new Buffer(_data[i], 'ascii'), function(err, results) {
       if(err!=null)
       {
         console.log('Error: ' + err);
       }
       else
       console.log('Results ' + results);
    });
}
});

serialPort.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); });
```

Comment: I am going to try bro :)

Comment: what node saying now ?

Comment: Are you sure about your COM3 port ?

Comment: I can read like this the arduino data
int i=0;
void loop()
{
delay(100);
Serial.println(i++);

}

I can read this result like 1-2-3-4-5-6-7

Comment: try my edit, if there are errors you will catch them !

Comment: And what is the node output ? the full output including 'open'

Comment: nothing . When i write var _data='try'; The output is result : undefinded three times

Comment: ok instead of creating a buffer try to write text directly : ` serialPort.write('test sending', function(err, results) {...}`

Comment: Again i cant send data from JavaScript to Arduino . Again result is undefinded...

Comment: the write function didn't send you 'results' ^^ if there is no error, your message is correctly sent

Comment: Can you give me your fb adress for help :( Connect my computer ? :(